# ReachabilityWithAddress error giving it an ip address

Tags: iphone, ip-address, connectivity

hey Im trying to see if I can connect to an IP address.

My code atm:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h"

@implementation ViewController
struct sockaddr_in ;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

Reachability *d = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:const struct sockaddr_in     ???????];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [d currentReachabilityStatus];
//NetworkStatus internetStatus = [d currentReachabilityStatus];
if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus!= ReachableViaWWAN)){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No internet" message:@"No internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
   [alert release];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *notify = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet" message:@"There is internet!(not)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"funny" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [notify show];
    [notify release];  

    }
}
```

Can someone tell me plz how to make this work?

I have no idea how to insert an ip address there...

Comment: Why don't you try reading the example that Apple provides?

Comment: Ye I have read it, and dont fully understand it because this is the line they are saying; + (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) hostAddress;

I need to fill in the host address but my question is now how, what do u recommend?

Comment: Like I said - check the EXAMPLE Apple provides. It's there for a reason - it shows you a complete example of how to do this. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this sample in Reachability sample provided by apple, hope you get the idea.

```
//Change the host name here to change the server your monitoring
remoteHostLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Remote Host: %@", @"www.apple.com"];
//commented this line in the applicationDidFinishLaunching of ReachabilityAppDelegate.m file
//hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
 struct sockaddr_in tAddr;
tAddr.sin_len = 16;
tAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
struct in_addr  address;
address.s_addr = htons(0x4a7de048);
tAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 //http://74.125.224.72/ this ip adress is for google
 //4a7de048 **updated** Hexadecimal representation of IP address 74.125.224.72

hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&tAddr] retain];
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! This works. Now I see where they had put the explanation of how I had to write the structure omg..

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
    struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;
    bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
    localWifiAddress.sin_len = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
    localWifiAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x0A0A0A7B); // hex representation of your local IP

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&localWifiAddress];    
    reachability.key = kLocalWiFiConnection;
    return [reachability isReachable];
```